# Use of O_APPEND

Tags: c, linux

I am getting Bad file Descriptor Error when running this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main() { 
  int fd;
  char buff[50];
  char wrt[4]="Fine";
  fd = open("temp.txt",O_APPEND);
  if (fd == -1) {
    perror("agia error");
  } else { 
    int cw = write(fd, wrt,4);
    if (cw == -1) {
      perror("Errori");
    }
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: In future use four spaces for indenting pieces of code (go on the tour - the help pages)

Comment: What is the file permissions for `temp.txt`?

Comment: You need to select a writing mode `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` at least, and then add `O_APPEND`, thus `O_WRONLY|O_APPEND` for example.

Comment: Please post valid code - `main()` must return `int`, and you need to include `<unistd.h>` and `<stdio.h>` to declare `open`, `write`,  `close` and `perror`.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've fixed the syntax errors and missing includes. But `void main()` should be fine, isn't it?

Comment: See [What should main() return in C and C++?](/q/204476) - and good compilers will complain if you get it wrong.

Comment: @hek2mgl you are still missing includes. `write` needs `unistd.h`. `perror` requires `stdio.h`. The compiler is surely warning you about implicit declarations - are you ignoring the warnings?

Comment: @TobySpeight I mean for sure, I would already return an int just to give back my return status, so every non trivial C program will do it. But seriously say that gcc isn't a good compiler?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` is a good compiler ;-)

Comment: Oh, got it. You see, my C knowledge is more than rusty....

Answer (score 0):

While the answer was given and someone even pointed out lack of necessary headers (not all), this cannot be left as is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Missing headers for open(2).

```
void main() {
```

This should be int main(void).

```
  int fd;
  char buff[50];
```

Unused variable.

```
  char wrt[4]="Fine";
```

Incorrect. "Fine" is 4 chars long, which means for a proper nul termination this requires a buffer of **5** characters. Fortunately you don't need to specify the size as char wrt[] = "Fine"; will do that for you. Except here likely don't want such a buffer but want char *wrt = "Fine"; instead.

```
  fd = open("temp.txt",O_APPEND);
```

Bad flag usage already mentioned.

```
  if (fd == -1) {
    perror("agia error");
```

Return an error, not only print that something happened.

```
  } else { 
    int cw = write(fd, wrt,4);
```

Error-prone repetition of the number 4. It should use sizeof if you have a bufer (and possibly subtract 1) or strlen.

```
    if (cw == -1) {
      perror("Errori");
    }
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a writing mode `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` at least, and then add `O_APPEND`, thus `O_WRONLY|O_APPEND` for example. – Jean-Baptiste Yunès